# Number keypad with missing keys in ios9

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9

Does anyone know why an issue like this in iOS9 native Number Pad Occurs.

[image]

This only happens in one of the viewcontollers and in the rest it works fine.

I have set the textfield keyboard type from the interface builder and not via code.Please advice how to overcome this issue.

Edited:

ScreenShots from Interface builder,
[image]

Comment: can you add some additional

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I have not done anything via code to alter the properties of the UItextfield. So what additional information do you need?

Comment: no I am not ask your code , show textfield keyboard type from the interface builder, what you selected in attributre inspector

Comment: I have added the screen shots from interface builder

Comment: bro where is your UIKeyboardType , I need that only no need of other images

Comment: no Idea friend, I tried my self in here its shows perfectly

Comment: Same problem here. I'll let you know if I find the reason...

Comment: the problem it setting the Appearance to black for the NumberPad.If u set it to default it will be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when configuring the keyboard type in Interface Builder.

The problem disappears if I set the keyboard type in my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
eanTF.keyboardType = .NumberPad
```

EDIT: I've also set the Appareance to `default` (in Interface Builder) in the commit.

Comment: the problem was not with setting the keyboard.it was the setting Appearance to black that caused the problem for me.

Comment: I've juste re-checked my git commit and I've also changed the Appearance to "default". That might be it then :) Thanks !