# Why does the number pad do this (iOS 9)?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios9, uikeyboard

I believe this began with iOS 9 but it may also have been one of the later releases of iOS 8. Basically, numberpad pops up but the actual characters on each button are gone (1-9, 0). I've truncated the top half of this image for confidentiality:

[image: this is on the 6s, but it's been confirmed to happen on earlier devices as well]

Comment: Any messages in the console? Show the code for this.

Comment: "Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 1336863583_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default" -- but I don't know if it's related for certain, but it seems it may be.

Comment: That's clearly related.

Comment: Ok yes, it certainly looks to be. It's also happening on the regular keyboard but only the "Space" text, Global/Emjoi picture and "Done" text are missing, everything else is there. Also, I can't find the consistency between devices. For instance, the missing numberpad is on all devices where it occurs but it's not just this app, a co-worker saw it happen in an Apple app as well. The missing Space bar is only on the 6s while the missing number pad is on all devices. So maybe it's just an OS bug?

Comment: @rmaddy No, I don't think it's related. I see that "can't find keyplane" message with the keyboard all the time. And my characters aren't missing.

Comment: @TonyFriz I say file a bug report.

Comment: Hmm. All right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when setting the keyboard type in IB. But setting it programatically in the `viewDidLoad` method solved the issue for me ([see my answer on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163790/number-keypad-with-missing-keys-in-ios9/34022469#34022469)).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10401502)

Comment: I've edited to have a more precise. Let me know if it's still not clear enough ;)